# How can you check for actions (on screen buttons) during the NStimer event (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, input, timer

I am trying to program something like the old Simon memory game.

Having some issues when trying to set up the user input section which i imagined to be something like

- Run through the current array for each item in 'simons memory'
- Start timer
- if no input for the timer duration then game over
- if input correct - reset timer - continue on next item
- if input incorrect - play annoying sound - end while loop - check score against hi score
  and update.

Was wanting to use NSTimer but not sure how to check for input during the timer.  I am a newbie to this so please be kind or not I can take it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using SpriteKit ? Also, you should always show what you have tried so far to show an effort in solving the issue. Stackoverflow is not a pool of programmers waiting to write the whole solutions for you :) but rather people eager to help when you are stuck.

Comment: I was using just normal single page application, should this be used with SpriteKit in your opinion ?  I thought the whole thing could be handled with timer to be honest but as I mentioned I am fairly new with iOS.
Also, I wasn't expecting people to write the code for me and I have made several attempts.  I think I have to go back to basics with Xcode / Swift to ensure I am doing things correctly
Thanks for the input

Comment: It can be easily accomplished with SpriteKit and its SKSpriteNodes, in conjuction with touchesBegan  method and few other useful methods like nodeAtPoint...Of course you don't have to use SpriteKit for this , it is doable with or without it... I was just wondering about how you are trying to solve this. Still, you should really update your question with your attempts to solve the issue. That way it's more likely you will get an useful answer, and you are not risking of being downvoted . For more hints see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

use the timer to disable the input section and then move to game over

If there **is** input, check it in the view controller, and deal with the timer from there - to either continue, or end the game